# Styling line using attribute from GeoJSON object in Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, geojson, html, css

I have a problem styling my lines using the exported attribute from QGIS from within Open Studio Code. I have attached screenshots to help better understand the problem.

My popup is able to take values from the attributes within the js file to populate the Name and Length of the lines, however I cannot set the line color to my desired colors as listed from within the same file. So when i simply enter 'red' as color, then all the lines turn red, but when i try to make it point towards the attribute in the js file, it doesn't work.
I have tried to create a var, const, and let to this value in color (circled) without success.

The HTML code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width-device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Barum</title>
        <!-- Leaflet css -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.3/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha256-kLaT2GOSpHechhsozzB+flnD+zUyjE2LlfWPgU04xyI=" crossorigin="" />
<style>
    body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    #map {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
    }

</style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="map"></div>
    </body>
</html>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.3/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha256-WBkoXOwTeyKclOHuWtc+i2uENFpDZ9YPdf5Hf+D7ewM=" crossorigin=""></script>
<script src="wege.js"></script>

<script>
   var map = L.map('map').setView([53.050191, 10.515445], 14);

// let stroke = feature.properties.colornam;
 var osm = L.tileLayer('https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
             attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
         });
        
         osm.addTo(map);

    var wege = L.geoJSON(wege, {
   onEachFeature: 
    // div stroke = feature.properties.color;
  function (feature, layer) {
     layer.bindPopup  ('<b>Name: </b>' + feature.properties.name + ' Weg'  + '<br><b>Length: </b>' + feature.properties.length + ' m')
  }, style: {
      color:  'black'
         

     } }).addTo(map)

        </script>
```

The javascript file containing the lines:

```
var wege = {
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "wege",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "fid": 1, "length": 2383, "name": "Classic", "color": "#69a0c8", "colornam": "Red" }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ 10.516359927808921, 53.046638822211143 ], [ 10.519027169521708, 53.044163901921969 ], [ 10.523460747535344, 53.043091788273891 ], [ 10.522829796628423, 53.03897964416398 ], [ 10.516493018629721, 53.039353515166354 ], [ 10.51777078431374, 53.045292985305771 ], [ 10.516262761750903, 53.046640060855957 ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "fid": 2, "length": 5219, "name": "Eier", "color": "#9ae82c", "colornam": "Blue" }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ 10.513506658257441, 53.051674094002585 ], [ 10.513315380804693, 53.051764399379238 ], [ 10.506032275021351, 53.052471932948833 ], [ 10.49742864748921, 53.054357507208699 ], [ 10.486053519485925, 53.055310522201935 ], [ 10.483905378167897, 53.05646013926588 ], [ 10.483763617796541, 53.056579069383709 ], [ 10.483883511793289, 53.057710138838019 ], [ 10.484949271639053, 53.057599205332572 ], [ 10.484967326382986, 53.056710502193688 ], [ 10.485989501324561, 53.056746555664077 ], [ 10.486668152182467, 53.056689258960148 ], [ 10.48681158496759, 53.056619121913982 ], [ 10.487891598051972, 53.058333757283457 ], [ 10.488203750544606, 53.058456778146912 ], [ 10.497960738406395, 53.059886717138582 ], [ 10.500219842569368, 53.059604398615811 ], [ 10.509505776012078, 53.059594332547881 ], [ 10.509154825005778, 53.056044863613124 ], [ 10.511094623486583, 53.055444190860634 ], [ 10.511302802535706, 53.0553732015536 ], [ 10.511507565004434, 53.055204620012823 ], [ 10.511833643932466, 53.053872636376987 ], [ 10.513397886856584, 53.052500496598675 ], [ 10.513429096785435, 53.05177271618286 ], [ 10.51353078163344, 53.051668905299287 ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "fid": 3, "length": 3399, "name": "Feld", "color": "#6f2bce", "colornam": "Pink" }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ 10.51654757635626, 53.055213700300506 ], [ 10.517036946778566, 53.058995710816326 ], [ 10.517220116692757, 53.060057599429818 ], [ 10.515520199559216, 53.066572008325132 ], [ 10.510564481157612, 53.066693614352985 ], [ 10.510398364324081, 53.066578561280146 ], [ 10.509385177655094, 53.056144458065802 ], [ 10.511404258049714, 53.055493956664037 ], [ 10.511907384981935, 53.053896107996501 ], [ 10.513471455379941, 53.052519087672991 ], [ 10.513494565928232, 53.051791410284785 ], [ 10.513572640299342, 53.051707426838838 ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "fid": 4, "length": 4093, "name": "Neue", "color": "#e08443", "colornam": "Yellow" }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ 10.516617377530237, 53.055196944671017 ], [ 10.517125010231585, 53.059037303219135 ], [ 10.524695602864922, 53.058642726899826 ], [ 10.526033756835467, 53.0598216023172 ], [ 10.527103963767878, 53.060296046129857 ], [ 10.529818367200404, 53.063034016738037 ], [ 10.530779853788527, 53.064095638227791 ], [ 10.530267437035926, 53.066615120438627 ], [ 10.51587514595192, 53.065500822140734 ], [ 10.517292830459592, 53.060181157018874 ], [ 10.516645819972021, 53.0551416621702 ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "fid": 5, "length": 3582, "name": "Wald", "color": "#e647a4", "colornam": "Black" }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ 10.512873646081731, 53.047378866989988 ], [ 10.511687424983208, 53.045890362931857 ], [ 10.512072262059068, 53.044850535831046 ], [ 10.511181327903333, 53.042538134593443 ], [ 10.511303655957189, 53.041404008795148 ], [ 10.510668862637177, 53.039928013503406 ], [ 10.509010830269032, 53.036980941500119 ], [ 10.508822034853667, 53.033429402635683 ], [ 10.512797118108114, 53.033164108184735 ], [ 10.513458361029224, 53.033546237953132 ], [ 10.515329493282719, 53.033327140980681 ], [ 10.516509755096337, 53.039267870636408 ], [ 10.517726859558168, 53.04532527732443 ], [ 10.516282241686696, 53.046632489877695 ] ] } }
]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the official Leaflet choropleth example at https://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth/, you'll see that you have to use GeoJSON layer `style` option to set set style function where you can set feature display style.

In your case relevant part of the code could look something like this:

```
var wege = L.geoJSON(wege, {
  onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
    layer.bindPopup  ('<b>Name: </b>' + feature.properties.name + ' Weg'  + '<br><b>Length: </b>' + feature.properties.length + ' m')
  },
  style: function (feature) {
    return {
      color: feature.properties.color
    };
  }
}).addTo(map);
```

Comment: I just want to ask about @TomazicM's answer if it is possible. 
In "color: feature.properties.color", is it necessary to put in the second 'color' the name of the field that has the different values that set the different colors? 
And secondly, does this work with an Ajax callback? Because I use this "<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js" ></script>" instead of "<script src="wege.js"></script>" which is used in the example. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @ANDRÉS If you have a new question, please post it as a separate question. And also one question per question, you comment has two questions.